# HTML form inputs create array of arrays

Tags: html, forms

I haveinputs that are defined like this in html:

```
 <input type="text" name="options[name][]" value ="Name" />
 <input type="text" name="options[selling_price][]" value = "10" />

 <input type="text" name="options[name][]" value ="Name 2" />
 <input type="text" name="options[selling_price][]" value = "20" />
```

...

When I process this on the server I get:

```
"options" => array:2 [▼
    "name" => array:2 [▼
      0 => "Name"
      1 => "Name 2"
    ]
    "selling_price" => array:2 [▼
      0 => "10"
      1 => "20"
    ]
```

What I would like to get is:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
    "name" => "Name"
    "selling_price" => 10
  ]
  1 => array:2 [▼
    "name" => "Name 2"
    "selling_price" => 20
  ]
]
```

Is this possible in html and make it dynamic so I can keep adding them in javascript?

The only way I have found to do it is to make a counter variable and do `options[counter][name]`

Comment: Because options[name][] creates an array of arrays

Comment: Your descriptions are very vague - what does "process this on the server" mean? What exactly are you trying to achieve here? A little context would go a long way

Comment: imho, OP states the actual result and expected result quite clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you came up with, adding the counter in the name, is correct. There is no built-in way to keep automatically increasing the counter while grouping specific form fields. So you'll have to keep track of the current count and increment this as well as putting it into the name attribute when adding a new set of fields.

Comment: My guess is because it seems like a vague answer - I'd try expanding it a little, preferably with example code

Comment: Well, it's all there is to say, really. OP knows about the dynamic array notation using empty square brackets `[]`, so there's no need to describe that, but there is no way to tell the server to group fields together. Nothing about that is vague. Are we rating SO answers by word length now?